# Using floating point numbers in imagefilledrectangle()

Tags: php

I'm using `imagefilledrectangle()` in my project. The 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th parameters accept point coordinates. The function description specifies the type of these should be `integer`. My problem is, I'm calculating these at run time and ensuring they are integers is proving difficult.

**My question:**

What are the consequences of using 'real numbers' instead of integers? For example:

```
imagefilledrectangle( $img, 1.2, 3.4, 4.5, 7.8, $color )
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledrectangle.php

Comment: you're dealing with pixels. there are no floats, so you could randomly have your drawn rectangles shifted by 1px "up" depending on how PHP decides to round off your float values. I'm guessing it'll just truncate down so `(1.1, 2.9)` would be treated the same as `(1, 2)`, but some day it could decide to round differently and become `(1, 3)`.

Comment: Thanks for the info @MarcB. Do you know how I could find out how PHP currently performs the rounding? I'd be interested to know

Comment: well, the function's [docs](http://php.net/imagefilledrectangle) explicitly say that the position args are ints. so you'd be bound by php's core float->int conversion results. so for now, your floats will just get truncated down: `echo (int)1.9` gives you `1`. maybe in php 7.0 or something it'll be changed to `round(1.9)` instead, giving you `2`.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help. Perhaps copy and past into an answer so I can give you some credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, your floats will get integerized by truncation, as per PHP's float->int conversion rules. So the function call will effectively be

```
imagefilledrectangle( $img, 1, 3, 4, 7, $color )
```

due to the function [explicitly defining](http://php.net/imagefilledrectangle) the position arguments as being `int`.

e.g.

```
echo (int)7.8; // outputs '7'
echo (int)1.2; // outputs '1'
```